# Redux-Toolkit: How to reject a "createAsyncThunk"?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

How to reject properly with `createAsyncThunk`. I have an asynchronous function that checks whether a mail address already exists or not. The response of the function is an empty string if there is no registered mail address and the user object of the registered user if the user exists.

```
export const checkIfEmailExists = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/checkIfEmailExists",
  async (mail) => {
    const response = await mailExists(mail).promise();
    if (response.user && response.user.length > 0) {
      reject();
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  }
);
```

In both cases the data comes back and no error occurs. How do I reject the `createAsyncThunk` in such a case?

Comment: Just throw the error and it'll reject

Comment: with `throw Error` ?

Comment: Yup. async functions will reject when an error is thrown `throw new Error('No data')`. Otherwise the async function will resolve when the function ends. You don't need to, and shouldn't call `reject` or `resolve` in an async function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `rejectWithValue` to [handle Thunk Errors](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors).

E.g.

```
import {
  configureStore,
  createAsyncThunk,
  createSlice,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

function mailExists(mail) {
  return {
    async promise() {
      // return { user: [{ name: 'teresa teng', mail }] };

      return { user: [] };
    },
  };
}

export const checkIfEmailExists = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/checkIfEmailExists',
  async (mail: string, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const response = await mailExists(mail).promise();
    if (response.user && response.user.length > 0) {
      return response.user[0];
    } else {
      return rejectWithValue('No user found');
    }
  }
);

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    data: {},
    error: null,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(checkIfEmailExists.fulfilled, (state: any, action) => {
        state.data = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(checkIfEmailExists.rejected, (state: any, action) => {
        state.error = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userSlice.reducer,
  },
});

store.dispatch(checkIfEmailExists('example@gmail.com')).then(() => {
  console.log(store.getState());
});
```

Output of the console:

```
{ user: { data: {}, error: 'No user found' } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering the question! I would like to work directly with the result of the "createAsyncThunk". However the "createAsyncThunk" always returns fullfilled. To work with the actual result i (fullfilled, rejected) inside the component i need to use "unwrapresult" from reudx toolkit. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results

Comment: @dan_boy thank you! took me an hour to find this solution

Answer (score 0):

here is slightly different syntax but the same thing:

Thunk Function:

```
export const fetchCountryData = createAsyncThunk(
    "",
    (anyNameOrEven_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        return axios
            .get(countriesAPIRoute)
            .then((el) => el.data)
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("err", err);
                return rejectWithValue("omg fail");
            });
    }
);
```

part of your Slice:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(fetchCountryData.rejected, (state, action) => {
            console.log("the info was rejected");
        });
```

basically if the responds from server is and Error, it will trigger the .REJECTED part

my server side code is:

```
app.get("/countries-api", (req, res) => {
    console.log("=======================");
    console.log("countries api");
    throw new Error("not found");
});
```