# Redux Thunk remains "fulfilled" even when I return a Promise.reject

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I've been using Redux for few time and i'm struggling with a Thunk answer...

In my slice, I'm calling an async function "handleBoxDeliveryAsync"

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
        .addCase(handleBoxDeliveryAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                if (state.scanMode === "remove") {
                  return;
                }
                const payload = action?.payload?.payload as Data;
                const box = payload.data.resource;
                //If box hasn't COLLECTED status
                if (box.status !== "COLLECTED") {
                  toast.warn("Le bac de collecte n'est pas disponible à la livraison");
                  return;
                }
                //If box hasn't been scanned yet
                if (!state.boxes.find((b) => b.external_id === box.external_id)) {
                  state.boxes.push({ external_id: box.external_id, weight: 0 });
                  toast.success("Le bac a été ajouté");
                  return;
                }
                //If box has already been scanned
                toast.warn("Le bac a déjà été scanné");
              })
...
```

this Thunk is responsible to play different functions depending on the "scanMode" (QRCode Reader)

```
export const handleBoxDeliveryAsync = createAppAsyncThunk(
  "collectDelivery/handleBox",
  async (code: string, store) => {
    try {
      if (store.getState().deliveryCollect.scanMode === "add") {
        return store.dispatch(getDeliveryBoxAsync(code));
      }
      if (store.getState().deliveryCollect.scanMode === "remove") {
        return store.dispatch(removeDeliveryBoxAsync(code));
      }
    } catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject(e); // Explicitly reject the promise if an error occurs.
    }
  }
);

export const getDeliveryBoxAsync = createAppAsyncThunk(
  "collectDelivery/getBox",
  async (code: string) => {
    try {
      return await getBox(code);
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  }
);

export const removeDeliveryBoxAsync = createAppAsyncThunk(
  "collectDelivery/removeBox",
  async (code: string, thunk) => {
    if (
      thunk
        .getState()
        .deliveryCollect.boxes.map((b) => b.external_id)
        .includes(code)
    ) {
      return Promise.resolve(code);
    }
    return Promise.reject(code);
  }
);
```

My problem is that when "getDeliveryBoxAsync" is rejected, "handleBoxDeliveryAsync" is still considered as "fulfilled". Any idea why?
Thanks a lot

I tried to handle error and Promises

Comment: `getDeliveryBoxAsync(code)` runs asychronously and will not throw an error. It returns the value of `store.dispatch(getDeliveryBoxAsync(code))` _before_ it throws an error in a promise.

Comment: You might wanna look into this thread on how to reject an action properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67548581/redux-toolkit-how-to-reject-a-createasyncthunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! I moved my logic in to the "getDeliveryBoxAsync"

```html
.addCase(getDeliveryBoxAsync.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        const box = payload.data.resource;
        if (box.status !== "COLLECTED") {
          toast.warn("Le bac de collecte n'est pas disponible à la livraison");
          return;
        }
        //If box hasn't been scanned yet
        if (!state.boxes.find((b) => b.external_id === box.external_id)) {
          state.boxes.push({ external_id: box.external_id, weight: 0 });
          toast.success("Le bac a été ajouté");
          return;
        }
        //If box has already been scanned
        toast.warn("Le bac a déjà été scanné");
      })
      .addCase(getDeliveryBoxAsync.rejected, (_, { error }) => {
        if (error.code === "ERR_BAD_REQUEST") {
          toast.warn("Le bac n'existe pas");
          return;
        }
        toast.warn("une erreur est survenue");
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The `handleBoxDeliveryAsync` is synchronously returning, e.g. resolving, the result of dispatching either of the `getDeliveryBoxAsync` or `removeDeliveryBoxAsync` actions, which both do their own asynchronous work. By the time either of them encounter any issues and throw/reject, it's too late, `handleBoxDeliveryAsync` resolved with a value that is another Promise.

## Solution

Seems you would like to ***wait*** for the result of either `getDeliveryBoxAsync` or `removeDeliveryBoxAsync` actions to resolve prior to allowing `handleBoxDeliveryAsync` to settle. You also don't need to explicitly return `Promise.resolve`/`Promise.reject` when using `createAsyncThunk` actions, Redux-Toolkit handles this for you.

For more details see [Handling Thunk Results](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results).

```js
export const getDeliveryBoxAsync = createAppAsyncThunk(
  "collectDelivery/getBox",
  // thrown/rejected will be caught/handled in handleBoxDeliveryAsync
  (code: string) => getBox(code),
);
```

```js
export const removeDeliveryBoxAsync = createAppAsyncThunk(
  "collectDelivery/removeBox",
  async (code: string, thunkApi) => {
    const { deliveryCollect: { boxes } } = thunkApi.getState();

    if (boxes.map((b) => b.external_id).includes(code)) {
      return code; // <-- fulfilled
    }
    return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(code); // <-- rejected
  }
);
```

```js
export const handleBoxDeliveryAsync = createAppAsyncThunk(
  "collectDelivery/handleBox",
  async (code: string, thunkApi) => {
    const { deliveryCollect: { scanMode } } = thunkApi.getState();

    try {
      if (scanMode === "add") {
        // await & return the unwrapped result
        return await thunkApi.dispatch(getDeliveryBoxAsync(code)).unwrap();
      }
      if (scanMode === "remove") {
        // await & return the unwrapped result
        return await thunkApi.dispatch(removeDeliveryBoxAsync(code)).unwrap();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // There was a thrown error or rejected Promise, will reject
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(e);
    }
  }
);
```